# How to find min value in SQL, if there are two identical?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

*What can I do to get the minimum value out of a column if there are two or more of the same value?

```
name   |   age
--------------
Peter  |   25
Andre  |   31
John   |   18
Lisa   |   31
Dick   |   29
Jen    |   18
```

I want the name(s) of the youngest person(s). min(age) just returns the first one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE age = (SELECT min(age) FROM table)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please tick the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `GROUP_CONCAT()` to group all the names into a list.

Something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name), age FROM people GROUP BY age ORDER age ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourTable where age = (select MIN(age)) from yourTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`select name,age from test.new_table where age = (select min(a.age) from test.new_table a)`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY age LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This will still only return one result.